# How can I update the state when the structure of my state is a tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using hooks and I have a state like the one below:

```
const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState([
  {
    name: "test",
    type: "record",
    children: [
      {
        name: "test1",
        type: "record",
        children: [
          {
            name: "test2",
            type: "record",
            children: [
              {
                name: "test3",
                type: "record",
                children: [
                  {
                    name: "test4",
                    type: "record",
                    children: [{ name: "test5", type: "record", children: [] }],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

The UI is separated into three components like below.

```
const Hierarchy = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <HierarachyTree data={treeData} />
    </div>
  );
};

const HierarchyTree = ({data = []}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((tree, index) => (
        <HierarachyTreeNode node={tree} index={index} data={data} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const HierarchyTreeNode = ({ node, index, data = [] }) => {
  const [childVisible, setChildVisiblity] = useState(false);
  const hasChild = node.children ? true : false;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <RowInputContainer>
        <InputFieldWrapper>
          {hasChild && !childVisible ? (
            <ButtonIcon onClick={() => setChildVisiblity((value) => !value)}>
              <KeyboardArrowRightIcon />
            </ButtonIcon>
          ) : (
            <ButtonIcon onClick={() => setChildVisiblity((value) => !value)}>
              <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
            </ButtonIcon>
          )}
          <input type="text" className={classes.input} placeholder="Field Name" />
        </InputFieldWrapper>
        <span>{node.type}</span>
      </RowInputContainer>
      {hasChild && childVisible && (
         <HierarchyTree data={node.children} />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

**My Question**

**How am I going to update the state if I want to modify the name of test3 or let's say I want to add items into the children array of test5?**

**This structure is dynamic so the hierarchy might be even deeper.**

Comment: I would recommend using a useReducer for complex state like this. Also a useful library to make it easier is immer, which you can use with useState and useReducer

Comment: I would recommend watching this video - [immer tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kC5fHlir4E)

Comment: @jake_prentice thank you, I appreciate your advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to keep the tree state in the higher level component and notify it if something changed in one child component.

When something change the base component recreate the tree, change the value in the new tree and setState with the new tree to trigger the rendering.

A possible function to do this can be:

```
const onChange = (node: TreeNode, checked: boolean) => {
    if (node === undefined || tree === undefined) {
        return;
    }

    const newTree = cloneTree(tree);

    if (node === tree) {
        propagateChecked(newTree, checked);
    } else {
        // find the node in tree
        let q: Array<TreeNode> = [newTree!];
        while (q.length !== (0 as number)) {
            const curr = q.pop();
            if (curr === undefined) {
                throw Error();
            }

            if (curr.type === 'dir') {
                for (let i = 0; i < curr.children.length; i++) {
                    const child = curr.children[i];

                    // WARNING: name must be unique!
                    if (child.name === node.name) {
                        // do the change into curr node
                        propagateChecked(curr.children[i], checked);
                        curr.checked = curr.children.every((x) => x.checked);
                    }

                    if (child.type === 'dir') {
                        q.push(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    setTree(newTree);
};
```

Here an example with the File System and the checked state for each entry.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nrrpvj